# Is Google map mobile SDK no longer free?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

According to this link :

[Google price guide](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/)

Google has changed it's prices from 11 June.
Is that mean using google map SDK for mobile devices is no longer free ?

Comment: You get $200 of free usage a month

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes and no.
You'll need an API key and a valid billing method. That being said, the first 200$ (I assume USD) of usage is free

> We’ve heard that you want simple, easy to understand pricing that
>   gives you access to all our core APIs. That’s one of the reasons we
>   merged our Standard and Premium plans to form one pay-as-you go
>   pricing plan for our core products. With this new plan, developers
>   will receive the first $200 of monthly usage for free. We estimate
>   that most of you will have monthly usage that will keep you within
>   this free tier.

From https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

After that, your credit card will be charged. To estimate your usage you can refer to this pricing table: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Comment: And mobile SDK usage is actually free with those new rules too

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/ - "Mobile Native Dynamic Map Loads"

Comment: "Free Maps usage for iOS, Android, and Embed (for displaying maps only)" In a way it's free yes

Comment: @Marco Is that mean using marker or drawing rout is not free ?

Comment: Indeed, drawing route is not free. You will pay for Directions request to get points of your polyline.

Comment: @xomena I mean set an array of points by my self and drawing it on the native mobile map , not using direction api of Google!

Comment: Is there a way to have projects that just aren't allowed to exceed the free quota and rather stop displaying maps in that case?

Comment: Hello, @Marco if i enable billing so after one month or more Google will take money from my credit card without asking me or something?

Answer (score 12):

All the below points are taken from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/).

---

@Marco's answer is correct on one point: you need an API key to have full access to the service.

> Also, in June 2016 we announced that we would stop supporting keyless usage, meaning any request that doesn’t include an API key or Client ID. This will go into effect on June 11th, and keyless access will no longer be supported. At that time, **keyless calls to the Maps JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps watermarked with “for development purposes only.”** Keyless calls to any of the following APIs will return an error: Maps Static API (including Static Street View), Directions API, Distance Matrix API, Geocoding API, Geolocation API, Places API, Roads API, and Time Zone API.

Here they are talking about the *Javascript API* but I could not find contradictory information about other APIs (iOS, Android) so I believe this applies to all APIs.

---

#### About billing

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/) says the following:

> **Is a credit card or billing account required?**
>
> Yes. Even though the first $200 a month is free, we ask for your credit card or billing account to cover any amount you spend over this free credit. When you’re billed, we'll credit your account for the first $200 of monthly usage. If your estimated usage will be above $200 a month and you don’t have a credit or debit card to set up a billing account, a local Google Maps Partner may be able to help.

In other words: **YES**, you need a billing account and a credit card (or a Google Maps Partner).

---

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/) is the **guide for existing users** and it says:

> **Is a credit card or billing account required?**
>
> Even though your first $200 of monthly usage is free, all Google Cloud Platform services require a credit card and billing account, to cover any amount you spend over this free credit. If you are billed, we'll credit your account for the first $200 of monthly usage. **If you choose not to add a billing account, there is a risk that if your usage exceeds $200 in a given month, your Maps API implementation will be degraded or other API requests will return an error.** If your estimated usage will be above $200 a month and you don't have a credit or debit card to set up a billing account, a local Google Maps Partner may be able to help.

In other words: **NO**, **existing users** don't need a billing account although it's strongly advised to have one.

---

<del>Clarification is needed from Google! Hopefully [this topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/XNRzLq79g6I;context-place=forum/maps) will get updated soon.</del>

Comment: I think they are still in a process of updating the docs and totally messed up. Let's wait and see.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answers, pricing is different for the "google map SDK for mobile devices", aka **Mobile Native** Dynamic/Static Maps for Android and iOS (which you mentioned in your question, and it's tagged with).

From the [Google Maps pricing sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/), it seems that all use of the Mobile Native APIs is free, while the traditional (web based) Dynamic and Static maps are chargeable as others described above. For static maps:

- First 28500 loads: free (with $200 monthly free usage).
- 0—100,000 calls per month: $2.00 per 1000 calls.
- 100,001-500,000 calls per month: something less than $2 per 1000 calls.
- Over 500,000 calls per month: contact sales.

And it's possible to add [usage caps](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) to force your usage of the web-based (chargeable) APIs to stay within the free tier. This does mean that your maps will **stop working** if your users cause you to exceed the usage caps, but at least you won't be charged.

Comment: if i enable billing so after one month or more Google will take money from my credit card without asking me or something

Comment: @DevAS only if your usage goes beyond the free tier. You can add a usage cap to ensure that it does not, as described above, and then you would never be charged.

Comment: Well, now my client couldn't accept his credit card when enabling a billing account so there's another service like Google maps?

Comment: is it free or not? i cant wrap my head around this

Comment: It's free up to $200/month which is 28,500 map loads. It's not free for heavy users.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free tier for up to $200 of usage, which most users won't pass I believe. So, small businesses won't be affected.

Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/

However, there's still no clarity on whether a Billing Account has to be set up with a valid Credit/Debit Card to get a new API Key. Google has a transition tool in place for those who already have the API key and are using it in their projects.

I'm a web developer and many of my clients are using GMaps on their website to show their business address. Not sure what Billing Account I'll have to use for all of them, because they're all finished projects and the client expects the maps to continue working as is. I can't possibly set the billing in my name and risk getting a huge bill some day. The current clients and the future clients have to be made aware of this new update. I concur it's like setting up a GSuite / Adwords account for your client.

Comment: Unfortunately for us developers this situation is very annoying... They could offer some extras for a price, but allow the basics without a card. I have dozens of clients that I'll have to contact now...

Comment: if i enable billing so after one month or more Google will take money from my credit card without asking me or something

Answer (score 2):

**OpenLayers** is a good alternative for google maps sdk, if you absolutely want a map.
It is free and does not require any account. **It worked for me!**

You can refer to the below link: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html