# Google Maps Android Sdk integration without Billing account ( no Credit Card)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

What if some one doesn't have a credit card and only want to rely on $200 credit as my user base will be very small.

From pricing page

> Are there other APIs or SDKs that are free to use?
>
> ```
> Yes. In addition to the $200 monthly free credit, all users get:
>
>     Free Maps usage for iOS, Android, and Embed (for displaying maps only)
>     Free Maps URLs
> ```

But when i try to create project in console, it ask me to setup billing account. I don't have any credit card. Please help.

Comment: It looks like there is no way around, but you are better off contacting Google support and asking them that question, instead of here.

Comment: Please provide the link or way to contact them, i tried contacting sales team and it says they don't provide support in my country. So what to do instead of asking fellow developers?

Comment: I don't have a link, but I'm sure there is a way to contact them from your country, but I don't think anyone will answer here, unless they know for sure and work for Google :) from the developer standpoint we can't do much

Comment: @LieForBananas you are wrong. You do **not** need to enable billing although Google encourages you to do so, in case you exceed the free quota. Please read their documentation carefully, especially the [Is a credit card or billing account required?](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/) point.

Comment: Well... reading the documentation again, I am not sure about my above statement anymore. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50234001/1238965) for more information.

Comment: @MrUpsidown yeah I read it again and it's very ambiguous, it says "all Google Cloud Platform services require a credit card and billing account" but then it almost contradicts it, I'm not sure either :)

Comment: Some years ago I was able to easily set a google maps key without any billing account; now the first thing they ask is for the credit card. [This link](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/) gives some info about the changes in their platform

Comment: Since this question is on hold, I can't post an answer, but maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182710/google-maps-api-error-deletedapiprojectmaperror) could help you (it worked for me, without a billing account, although I'm working with a site and not with Android development. But there is a Maps SDK for Android API)

Comment: Thanks @BrianHellekin much appreciated.

Comment: I just set one up and it says that credit card is to check that you're not a robot + that you'll never be billed without giving your agreement explicitely (so I guess that if you reach the quota on your app, the map won't load)